# Overwrite PrimeNG step component styling

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I am using

```
<p-steps [model]="items" [(activeIndex)]="activeIndex" [readonly]="false"></p-steps>
```

in my Angular component. In my component's stylesheet, I am trying to style the p-steps with no luck. When I change the style directly in the browser's developer tools, it works. I even tried to overwrite the style with Angular's

```
:host ::ng-deep
```

But it did not work. I want the steps to be aligned vertically, I dont want the border and I want the step numbers to be light grey and the selected step number to be light grey. What I want is the follwing:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-widget, .ui-widget * {
  float: none !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep .ui-steps {
  border: none !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep .ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-state-highlight .ui-steps-number {
  background-color: #757575 !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep body .ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-number {
   background-color: #bdbdbd !important;
}
```

I have also set

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

in my component.

Comment: Let me see try to play with your issue. I create custome components based on PrimeNG. I'm surprised the ng-deep didn't work. FYI erase the viewEncapsulation line. It's not good practice to use that

Comment: Have you tested my answer? If yes and it works please upvote it and mark it as correct answer

Comment: Hi, thanx, I will test it and let you know. However, I got it to work by slightly changing the answer of @fatemefazli.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the solution. You were missing a `::ng-deep`

```
::ng-deep .ui-widget, ::ng-deep.ui-widget * {
  float: none !important;
  color: red;
}
.ui-steps {
  color: red;
  border: none;
}
.ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-state-highlight .ui-steps-number {
  background-color: #757575;
}

.ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-number {
   background-color: red;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-jr2vaa

1. Avoid `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`
2. Avoid using
       `!important`
3. Start using SCSS
4. Don't put any custom code in
       your parent scss

[image]

Comment: I tested your solution and it did not work. It just took the standard styling as if I didn't even have any scss file with my own styling.

Comment: @YourReflection I added a picture. That's how it supposed to look like? Did you test it on stackblitz or you tested on your enviroment my solution?

Comment: yes, it looked like this and there was no run button. I tested your styling in my component afterwards and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

My Suggestion never override the CSS of any third party library as it is. If you want to override CSS property of any element first use your own class. Then add CSS properties. With the rule of [CSS specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) it will override the CSS properties easily without using !important and any other hack.

What I did to solve this issue I have added my own class **customestepper** and overridden the CSS properties like below:

```
<p-steps [model]="items" class="customstepper"></p-steps>
```

and then in **styles.css**

```
.customstepper .ui-state-highlight{
    background: #343a40;;

}
.customstepper .ui-steps .ui-steps-item.ui-state-highlight .ui-menuitem-link {
    color:#fff;
}
```

**Demo:** [Click to see the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-hmua4l?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html)
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9PGh.png)

Comment: Thanx @DirtyMind, but then I have to use "encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None". Otherwise it won't work. Is that a better solution to using "!important"? And for highlighting a selected step in another color than the rest of the steps it is still not working. It only works, when I use !important

Comment: Using your own class is the right way to override CSS. I dont think overriding CSS using :host ::ng-deep is good approach.

Comment: @YourReflection Yes if at all nothing is working then we can go with !important .

Answer (score 1):

you can add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and try this in your component css:

```
.ui-widget, .ui-widget * {
  float: none !important;
  color: red;
}
.ui-steps {
  color: red;
  border: none !important;
}
.ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-state-highlight .ui-steps-number {
  background-color: #757575 !important;
}

.ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-number {
   background-color: red !important;
}
```

or delete the `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` and put the above css in your global `styles.css` file.

first way [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-fjhqzr).

second way [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-riz8vl).

Comment: It's not good practice to use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` also putting it in the global css isn't good practice either

Comment: Then what would you suggest @PatricioVargas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this (decided not to use the vertical alignment):

```
body .ui-steps .ui-steps-item.ui-state-highlight .ui-steps-number {
 background-color: #757575 !important;
}
.ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-number {
 background-color: #bdbdbd !important;
}
.ui-steps:before {
 border: none !important;
}
```

I also needed to add the

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
```

in my component.

Another solution that works without adding encapsulation is this:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-steps .ui-steps-item.ui-state-highlight .ui-steps-number {
  background-color: #757575 !important;
}
::ng-deep .ui-steps .ui-steps-item .ui-menuitem-link .ui-steps-number {
  background-color: #bdbdbd !important;
}
::ng-deep .ui-steps:before {
  border: none !important;
}
```

Without using

```
!important
```

it does not work so far.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Btw you don't need :host, you also should avoid !importants as much as possible. This will make your code more mantainable

Comment: @PatricioVargas: i tried with not using :host and !important. Unfortunately, it didn't work, so I left it in : /

Comment: ughhh i wish i could help more